# Ruby Automatically select a option for select in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

I have a form that has a drop-down that goes from 1 to 10. I need it to automatically select 10 when the page is loaded though.

I've tried this

```
f.select(:load_priority, options_for_select(1..10), :selected => 10)
```

But that still keeps the default on 1. How would I make it select 10 from the get-go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<%= f.select(:load_priority, options_for_select((1..10), 10)) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

While using options_for_select, the default value can be passed as a second param.

Api guide url for reference, (http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

```
<%= f.select options_for_select((1..10), default) %>
```